# Angular2 - Store Images in Browser cache as Key-value pair form

Tags: javascript, angular, caching

I'm working in Angular2. In my app, I've to load excessive amount of images. But instead of loading those images for every reload, **I want to put those images into browser cache but in *key-value pair* form.**

I want something like following

```
<img src=getImageFromCache('image-key')/>
```

And when API returns image URL, then I want to put that image in browser cache like following

```
addImageToBrowserCache('image-key', 'image-url')
```

Any kind help, please?

Regards

Comment: Caching should be done by setting the correct headers on the server response, not like this.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use local storage of browser.

As:

`localStorage['img-key'] = 'img-url';`

or

`localStorage.setItem('img-key','img-url')`

Same for retrieving.

`localStorage.getItem('img-key')`

Comment: Muzammil, I want to store image as value, not image url

Comment: You've likely found your solution but for others coming here:

localStorage accept Strings only, so you can store the base64 string representation of an image like so:

`localStorage.setItem('img-key', 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg...')`

Then after retrieval it can be used in the src attribute, the browser will show the image :)
`<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg..." />`

Be aware that there is a hard limit on localStorage capacity (5mb) so it's not ideal to use for caching large amount of images.